# JTextField Alignment Error. Cannot align to the right

Tags: java, eclipse

I am attempting to align my TextField to print text/numbers from the right however, I am getting an syntax error saying "RIGHT cannot be resolved or is not a field." I did look up similar problems but could not find a solution to my problem.

```
GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
        TextField textField = new TextField(12);
        textField.setBackground(Color.white);
        Font font = new Font("",Font.PLAIN,46);
        textField.setFont(font);
        g.insets = new Insets(10,10,350,10);
        g.gridx = 0;
        g.gridy = 2;
        g.ipady = 0;
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(TextField.RIGHT);//Error on this line.
        panel.add(textField,g);
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

According with [JTextFieldDocumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setHorizontalAlignment(int)) the method `setHorizontalAlignment` is expecting an `int` argument, try this:

```
textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
```

or this:

```
textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```